# Where can I get a legendary potion?

Tags: diablo-iii

The game guide shows new [legendary potions](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/potion/) that are infinite use with a special effect.  Where can I get one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it anywhere, but only on the Torment difficulty. http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9582428450

Comment: The link is broken. :/